# Turning Off Autocorrect on Internet Explorer by passing in parameter in webdriver/protractor?

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am testing on IE11 (Windows7) using Protractor 1.5.0, and my tests are failing because the text that I post on a message forum are being autocorrected. Is there a way to turn off autocorrect by tweaking something in my config file? Such a tweak would be ideal since I'm experiencing the same issue when I run the tests remotely on Sauce Labs.

Not experiencing this issue on Firefox, Safari, or Google Chrome.

Example:

> Expected 'sint quis impedit officiis harum cupiditate facilis maiores
>   aliquam repellendus ex voluptatem  commode voluptatibus incident
>   dolor' to equal 'sint quis impedit officiis harum  cupiditate facilis
>   maiores aliquam repellendus ex voluptatem commodi voluptatibus
>   incidunt dolor'.

Comment: Could you please provide the relevant code that is responsible for posting the text? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There should a way to turn it off through a desired capability (well, this is IE, you can only hope about it).

What usually helps in automation is trying things manually first - see what you can do to force it accept the text with typos or mistakes.

As far as I see it currently, IE would leave the text as is if you would type it 2 times:

```
elm.sendKeys(text);  // IE would autocorrect the spelling here
elm.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a"));
elm.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
elm.sendKeys(text);  // this time IE would not apply autocorrect
```

FYI, isntead of `CTRL+A` and `BACKSPACE`, [`elm.clear()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.clear) might also work in your case.

---

Another option would be to set the `value` of the `input` [through javascript](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript):

```
browser.executeScript('return $("input[name=\'myname\']").val("text here");');
```

Or, it should also work through `arguments`:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].val('text here');", elm).then(function() {
    // do smth
});
```

Comment: was really hoping that this would work (although it gave me 'undefined' until I changed `protractor.Key.BACKSPACE` to `protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE`)
but i tried stringing that sequence 3x in my code and it's still autocorrecting my words.
I feel like this brings me closer to solving my problem though, thanks!

Comment: @aricearice updated the answer with an another option. Hope that helps.

Comment: so I've found that the word 'dolores' and 'architecto' are generated by the Faker.js module that I'm using, and they are being auto-corrected to 'Dolores' and 'architect', respectively. 

If I enter these words manually, (after entering text then hitting backspace) 
'dolores' wouldn't autocorrect to 'Dolores' if I enter it first in a string of words and then backspace, but it would autocorrect if it's the second or third word.

Comment: @aricearice the first option though, I think, is a right direction. May be (try this) you should implement the following pattern: type word, remove it, type again etc - in other words, word-by-word..

Comment: blech, giving up for now and just using real sentences when testing on IE. Thanks for the help, @alecxe

Comment: @aricearice if I would have time later today - I'll play around with it on browserstack. Will update you in case. Thanks.